# Erro ao pegar dados para uma view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Estou tentando trazer os dados para uma view para efetuar alguns testes no Laravel mas não está dando certo

**Controller**

```
class ProfileController extends Controller
{
private $aluno;
private $request;



public function __construct(Aluno $aluno, Request $request)
{

    $this->aluno = $aluno;
    $this->request = $request;



}


   public function index()
    {
        $id = '39';


        $alunos = $this->aluno
            ->select('*')
            ->where('id', '=', $id)
            ->get();


        return view('profile.index', compact('alunos'));

    }
```

Model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\Profile;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;



class Aluno extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'aluno';
}
```

Comment: Vc tem uma variável `$alunos` e no compact está apenas `aluno`, qual é o erro?

Comment: Desculpa foi erro de digitação o erro que traz é este 

Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$nome (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\curso\resources\views\profile\index.blade.php)


Mas tenho certeza que o erro não é na View pois já trouxe esses dados de uma outra forma agora que quero trazer de um ID especifico não esta dando certo

Comment: Coloca o model tbm

Comment: Coloquei o Model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na view você deve estar tentando acessar a propriedade diretamente `$aluno->name`, porém o  método `get()` retorna uma coleção (`Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection`).

Para retornar um resultado apenas, você deve utilizar o método `first` ou `find`.

Tente isso:

```
$aluno = $this->aluno->select('*')->where('id', '=', $id)->first();
```

Ou simplesmente:

```
$aluno = $this->aluno->find($id);
```

Comment: Deu certo Rafael Obrigado a 2ª opção eu havia feito dessa forma pq acho mais pratico mas eu colocava um id de um aluno e na View trazia de outro aluno